# How to Count Total Number of pixel of padded value used in image(Padded Image)?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pixel

I have one binary image so it has only 2 value like 0 and 1.  After, I convert this into a padded image of different values, like the image will have curve shape.  I took a 3 X 3 matrix of value and if i get curve shape then I padded the image with 1, or any number.  I use 15 different types shape values like junction point, end point etc.

After, I give the values 1 to 15 - or the appropriate number according its shape.  As such, I am getting an image like:

## Figure

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I would like to count how many 1s there are in the image, followed by 2s, 3s, etc. up to 15. For example,
as shown in the figure, if the pad number was 5, the total number of pixels would be 3.  If the pad number was 1, the total number of pixels would be 6.

Comment: Probably it would help if you add additional tags (ex. programming language, libs you use related to image processing).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`histc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html):

```
>> im = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0
          0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
          0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0
          0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]; %// data
>> values = 1:15; %// possible values
>> count = histc(im(:), values)
count =
     6 %// number of 1's
     0 %// number of 2's, etc
     0
     0
     3
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
```

Or compute it manually with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
>> count = sum(bsxfun(@eq, im(:), values(:).'), 1)
>> count =
     6     0     0     0     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

I can also suggest using [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
im = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]; %// data - borrowed from Luis Mendo

counts = accumarray(im(:) + 1, 1);
counts(1) = []

counts =

     6
     0
     0
     0
     3
```

Note we have to offset by 1 as `accumarray` starts indexing the output array at 1.  Because you want to disregard the 0s, I simply take the `counts` result and remove the first entry.  This result agrees with what you are seeking. The first element is how many 1s we have encountered, which is 6.  The last element is how many 5s you have encountered, which is 3.  Because 5 is the largest number encountered in your image, we can say that all symbols after 5 (6, 7, 8, ..., 15) have a count of 0.

Comment: Thank u sir.. how to create histogram of this image?

Comment: Uh...  I thought I did create a histogram? Did you not read any of our answers?

Comment: Your Code Work Fine... But I dnt knw how to creat histogram... like one x direction total different shape like 1 to 15 and one y number of pixel number count ( like for 1 = 45  pixel so on....)

Comment: Try with this code: `bar(1:numel(counts),counts,'histc');`